# How to read and display one:many tables in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to combine two things which are already know how to do, but can't figure out how to combine them. Here is what I want to achieve:

I have a database with locations and events. There are several events in each location. I will be using PHP to query the database and output the code needed to display search results. I want something similar to the below:

```
<div id="location">
    <p>Location1</p>
    <div id="event">Event1</div>
    <div id="event">Event2</div>
    <div id="event">Event3</div>
</div>
 <div id="location">
    <p>Location2</p>
    <div id="event">Event4</div>
    <div id="event">Event5</div>
    <div id="event">Event6</div>
</div>
```

I know that I can use select distinct to get the unique value of each location, and know that I can use a normal select statement to get all the events, however how do add all the events inside the location div?

My current PHP looks like this:

```
$sql ="SELECT location, event from events";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $location = $row['location'];
    $event = $row['event'];


    echo "<div id="location">
             <p>$location</p>
             <div id="event">$event</div>
          </div>";
}
```

My current code adds duplicates of the same location with 1 unique event in each. Even if I use select distinct I get the same results. How do I group the events have have the same location?

Comment: not an answer - but why you hold events and locations in same table?

Comment: Public service announcement: `mysql` functions are now depreciated. You need to switch to `mysqli`

Comment: @Machavity Those functions are deprecated. They may or may not have lost some of their intrinsic value as a consequence.

Comment: Andrew - I agree with nevermind. If you have your events and locations in different tables, you can read your locations first, and loop through those. For every iteration of the loop, read your events for the current location and then loop through those. You'll end up with two nested loops, which you can order as you wish.

Comment: @nevermind I actually have a join between the events and locations tables but didnt want to over complicate the question.

Comment: @halfer - Er, not quite. Surely, that's what JOINs are for!

Comment: @halfer That is nuts! But hey, it's your party!

Comment: @halfer Optimisation? That's not optimisation. That's just a multiple trips to the sql server instead of one. But you know that, so I'll leave it there.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should write something like:

```
$sql ="SELECT location, event from events";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$prevlocation = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $location = $row['location'];
    $event = $row['event'];


    if ( $prevlocation != "" )            // Close previous div if needed
    {
        echo "</div>";
    }

    if ( $location != $prevlocation )
    {
       echo "<div id='location'><p>$location</p>";
       $prevlocation = $location;
    }
    else
    {
       echo "<div id='event'>$event</div>";
    }
}

echo "</div>";   // Close last div
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have join of two tables, let's assume that your query looks like this:

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM events
JOIN locations ON
locations.id=events.loc_id";
```

And then, within one loop, get events and location arrays:

```
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$locations = array();
$events= array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $location = $row['location'];
    $event = $row['event'];
    $loc_id=$row['loc_id'];
    $id=$row['id'];


    $events[]=$loc_id.'%'.$event;

    if(!in_array($id.'%'.$location,$locations)) { // avoid duplicate entries
    $locations[]=$id.'%'.$location; 

}

}
```

And, another loop (+loop inside loop):

```
for($i=0;$i<count($locations);$i++) {

    $location=explode('%',$locations[$i]);
            echo "<div class='location'>\n
    <p>$location[1]</p>\n"; 

    for($j=0;$j<count($events);$j++) {

    $event=explode('%',$events[$j]);

    if($event[0]==$locations[$i][0]) {  

    echo "<div class='event'>".$event[1]."</div>";
    }



    }
    echo "</div>";  
    }
```

Not so elegant, but it is working, and produces valid HTML. :)
First, i wanted to make two associative arrays, and to compare keys, but i couldn't, because i couldn't convert ID keys to strings, so i made it with explode (% is separator between key and value).